# Python Speech Recognition ALSA issue in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am using rear jack microphone and it is working perfectly with sound recorder or like with google search. 
But when I am using it with Python speech recognition, I do not know whats going on.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
s = sr.Microphone()
```

when I run this, it shows:

```
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:618:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
```

Comment: What type of this error is?

Answer (score 0):

I tested in the console import pyaudio

```
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:638:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2564:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
```

Maybe the firefox browser uses my usb port for this.
I get deeper in the understanding of the usb connection of my webcam